# Modify CSS before page loads in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I want to prevent an specific `background-image` being displayed on a page, possibly using jquery. However, the page and DOM is loaded before the JS is activated.

What I want to do is the following:

```
.pagelayout-login #page{
background: none;
}
```

I have tried the same in JQuery using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".pagelayout-login #page").css("background","none");

});
```

However, both modify the stylesheet **after** the image has been loaded and displayed.

If I add `"run_at : "document_start"` inside my `content scripts`, the CSS get's overridden by the page's CSS.

Is there a way to prevent the background from being displayed before it starts loading?

Comment: why don't you do it the other way? Append the image with Javscript and don't have it by default.

Comment: @NicoO Maybe because they don't have control over the page where the image is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the CSS at the beginning :

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {code:'my css code', allFrames:false, runAt:"document_start"});
```

or add a script at the end like this :

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:'my script code', allFrames:false, runAt:"document_end"});
```

with the CSS, you need to be the first, because it's a "Cascading Style". 
with the script, it must be the last change.

You can try to add !important to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think this would be a lot easier the moment you remove the $(document).ready, everything inside that function runs *after* the page has completed loading.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is in a Chrome extension, don't be afraid to use `!important` to ensure that your CSS overrides the page's CSS even if you `"run_at : "document_start"`:

```
.pagelayout-login #page{
background: none !important;
}
```

This may or may not prevent the image from loading since it's still being referenced by the page's CSS, but it will at least prevent it from displaying right away. You will need to conduct your own tests to determine if Chrome will still attempt to request the image during page load in spite of this.